# Dynamically bound elements with applyBindingsToNode not responding to changes

Tags: knockout.js

In this example I have a dynamically bound input and div to the same property.
But on altering text in input, changes are not reflected in the div element.

http://jsfiddle.net/rpuri/Bcps5/

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById('input-health'), {
    value: vm.status(),
    valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'
});
```

Declarative binding is not an option for me because I need to bind to shared elements in partial views (ASP.NET MVC).

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why the fact you need to bind shared elements in partial views means declarative binding is not an option. Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Because sometimes the select lists and input fields are used in create forms and search/filtering forms. I'm sharing forms as partial views throughout my application. The select lists are bound on server side using a cached repository.

Comment: What about using the template binding for that?

Comment: Templating is an option but my Html Helpers will have to contain knockout specific attributes e.g. dropdown.Attributes.Add("data-bind", "data-bind='template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }'"); Not sure if I want knockout.js concerns at this level.

Comment: Right, but the minute you've added KnockoutJS your templates are no longer _really_ html - they're Knockout views. They have the responsibility to handle all sorts of logic that templates usually don't have to handle. I can totally see why you'd want to create the binding from the other direction though (although I personally think it's a lot less readable a lot of people like it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are binding to the value of the observable instead of the observable itself.

Try:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById('health'), {
    text: vm.status, // <- not invoking status, binding to the observable itself.
    valueUpdate: 'keydown'
});

ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById('input-health'), {
    value: vm.status,  
    valueUpdate: 'keydown'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hwQsm/

Comment: Great. But I realised my property is nested. So how would something like this work:  value: vm.Person().status?

Comment: That might work but I can't tell without seeing your code - Would you mind creating a short self contained code example?

Answer (score 0):

I used the preprocess feature (Knockout 3).

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: LastName, vuClass: 'text'" />
```

---

```
ko.bindingHandlers.vuClass = {
    preprocess: function (value, name, addBindingCallback) {
        if (value == "'text'") {
            addBindingCallback('valueUpdate', "['afterkeydown', 'blur']");
        }

        // ...
        // Check other values.
        // ...

        return value;
    }
};
```