# How to add additional event to already data-bound element in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have date control that looks like this.

```
<input data-bind="value: formatDateTime(ko.unwrap(Started)), css: { validationElement: validateItem(Started, 'Started') }, event: {
change: function(d, e) {
    if (Started != $(e)[0].target.value &amp;&amp; dateWheelShown == true) {
        $data.Started(dateToISO($(e)[0].target.value,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
    }
}
}, id: 'Started' + '_' + Id()" data-onthemove_dateformat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" class="Mobile_DateTimePick ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini" data-mini="true" name="Started" id="scoller1400844006695" readonly="">
```

To some of these date controls I need to add additional events on certain user actions.
  **How can I inject additional event to element that is already data-bound?**

Comment: Do you really need to? Is there no workaround?

Comment: @GôTô We'll I would prefer to avoid using hacks, I have well defined event handlers for those additional events I want to attach, and they are being used throughout system already. What workaround would you have in mind?

Comment: Well it depends why you need this. Maybe declare events from the begining but having an initial `if` clause to execute the code only under certain circumstances

Comment: @GôTô so what you're saying add all the events on element and then wrap the normal event handlers in something like function(){if(IsOnMouseOverEventActive){normalOnMouseOverEventHandler();}} for each type of event? I suppose this could work as a workaround.

Comment: Something like that, I don't have all the context, don't know if you can do that. Be careful with return values

Comment: Or create custom bindings! You can do almost anything there! Check the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for more info! For example the date validation you have there could be moved in a custom binding. This will make the HTML easy to read.(as it should be)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically bound elements with applyBindingsToNode not responding to changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164974/dynamically-bound-elements-with-applybindingstonode-not-responding-to-changes)

Comment: I think there was also something `ko.applyBindingsToNode` or `ko.applyBindingsToElement` in case you really want to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add event with `ko.applyBindingsToNode` function, e.g.

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, { 
                           event: {
                               keydown : function() {
                                   alert("onKeydown")
                               }
                           }
                       })
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPCb5/) *

* - Source of demo:
**Html**

```
<input id="inputId" data-bind="event: {
   change: function(d, e) {
       alert('onChange');
   }
}"/>
<button data-bind="click: addkeypressEvent">Add evend</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var vm = {
    addkeypressEvent: function()
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("inputId");
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, { 
                                   event: {
                                       keydown : function() {
                                           alert("onKeydown")
                                       }
                                   }
                               })
   }
}
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```