# Manually apply a bindinghandler through code in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm making a generic 'parent' bindinghandler, and want to reuse an Knockout bindinghandler in one of the child elements - without specifying them in the original tags with `data-bind`.

As an example try to think of a 'specialForm' bindingHandler that hooks up all kind of interactions to all the child elements. For one of those interactions I would like to reuse the plain `value: observable` and use that observable for further `computedObservables`.

So i have the element, the bindingHandler name, and the viewModel that I want to use for it. What is the best way to apply this?

One thing I could do is manually adding `data-bind="text: observable"`, but there are a few disadvantages:

- it's relatively ugly - I need to take into account when there are already other bindings. Doesn't feel good that it needs string manupulation.
- also variable lookup goes by name. Easier to break when there is a name clash. I rather have something that works within the current closure.

So: is there a better way?

Comment: I haven't understood well your question, but if I'm not wrong you want to bind data to elements inside your "parent node" without data-bind? Knockout bases its two-way binding using data-bind. You could though use ko's `applyBindingsToNode`. Please make a "better" example and I'd be helpful :)

Comment: `applyBindingsToNode` was indeed the answer. Thanks! I see similar questions that might be better formulated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164974/dynamically-bound-elements-with-applybindingstonode-not-responding-to-changes

Hm...delete the question?